# Which approach is better in for layout design of a long form

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments

I am making an android application in which I have long form divided in four parts.

**I have two option in which I can design layout for this**

1. I can make a single layout in which I can define 4 separated layouts and will make one visible at a time.(All things in single fragment)
2. I make 4 different fragments for 4 part of layout and easily navigate from one fragment to other. I have to pass information in bundle in this design however there is no need for this in previous case.

Tell me which is better and standard way of doing things of this kind and why?

Thanks

Comment: Prefer having user attention to one simple step at a time. You should divide the form sections into multiple `Fragment`'s with next and back navigation.

Comment: both the approach will have same display for user.

Comment: but I am asking which one is better and standard approach from programming point of view

Comment: 2nd approach is better!